# vue accessing async server method

Tags: spring, vue.js

Being rather new to vue I am trying to access an async server method with a vue client. The server is a standard spring boot application. It creates an export in a xlsx file and writes to the response object. So if the client calls the method after the file is shown as a button as for a usual download in the browser. Calling the method in sync mode works. Could you point me into a direction on how I can call the method in async mode from a client? I had a look at websockets but it looks rather difficult to grab.

```
@Async
@PostMapping("/plants")
public void export(HttpServletResponse response) {
  File file = aService.export());
  httpUtils.writeInResponse(response, file);
}
```

**Update**
The client call when the server returns in sync mode.

```
  export(exportParams) {
    return this.$http({
      url: "/myurl/plants",
      method: "POST",
      data: exportParams,
      responseType: "blob"
    });
  }
```

Comment: You have to make HTTP calls with VueJS. You can do it with `axios` in example

Comment: I call it with axios in sync mode which works. But in async it doesn't since it results in a timeout.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by sync mode with axios. Can you show code you try ?

Comment: I updated the original post with the client call. The post is sent and the client takes longer than the timeout.

Comment: Don't use `@Async` on controller methods, that is the wrong approach. Instead use the async programming model by returning an async response. For the client it doesn't matter if it is sync or async on the server, it is all about server utilization.